# Map & Extract an Inner List from Model

Tags: kotlin

I have this data class:

```
data class Model(val mId, val mList: List<AnotherModel>)
```

There is a list of them:

```
val fakeList: List<Model>
```

I want to extract & map `mList: List<AnotherModel>` as `List<NeoAnotherModel>`

The challenge here is `forEach` returns nothing (Unit)

```
Observable.just(fakeList).map { models: List<Model> ->
  val IWantNeoAnotherModelList = models.forEach { model: Model ->
    model.mList.map { list: List<AnotherModel> ->
      NeoAnotherModel(...)
    }
  }
}
```

I also checked the [documentation](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/collection-transformations.html) for some transformation function but no luck so far.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just use `flatMap` to extract models to one list and then `map` to convert them:

```kotlin
val models: List<NeoAnotherModel> = fakeList.flatMap { it.mList }.map { model: AnotherModel ->
    NeoAnotherModel(...)
}
```